# How do I use .NET Core's IdentityServer4 on .NET 4.6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I've been trying to follow the startup guide for [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html). I'm happy to make my authentication service a .net core application, but the services I'd like to authenticate are boring normal ASP.NET WebApi 2 projects.

So the setup [shown in the documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) won't work. There is no IApplicationBuilder, `app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication` is not a thing here. I'm not using the latest and greatest MVC stuff.

Is there any documentation for mixing Identity Server 4 with older applications? Is it it even supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Web API 2 you can use the Microsoft Katana JWT middleware, or our middleware for Katana:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation

Comment: Yep, thanks, client code looks the same whatever version I'm using.